# Testing React with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

As a newcomer in the world of enzyme: How can I test following construction?

```
return (this.FAQData.context[context])
        ? this.FAQData.context[context]
        : this.FAQData.context.default;
```

code coverage (istanbul) report:

[image]

**Following tests did not help, although they work successfully:**

```
it ("checks if FAQData has questions for a certain route", () => {
    let someRoute = '/dashboard';
    expect(wrapper.instance().FAQData.context[someRoute].length).not.to.be.null;
});

it ("checks if FAQData.context[someRoute] is true", () => {
    let someRoute = '/dashboard';
    let result = wrapper.instance().FAQData.context[someRoute] ? true : false;
    expect(result).to.be.true;
});
```

P.s. (Mocha + Chai + Enzyme + Istanbul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this,

```
return (this.FAQData.context[context])
        ? this.FAQData.context[context]
        : this.FAQData.context.default;
```

as below

```
return (this.FAQData.context[context] || this.FAQData.context.default);
```

To get the complete branch coverage, it would be better to share the code where you set the context in the mock component.

I couldn't elaborate on a comment, that's why added it as an answer.